# Exclude values from data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
Count Year
32   2018
346  2017
524  2016
533  2015
223  2014
1    2010
3    2008
1    1992
```

Is it possible to exclude the years 1992 and 2008. I tried different ways, but don't find a flexible solution. 
I would like to have the same dataframe without the years 1993 and 2008.

Many thanks in advance, 
jeemer

Comment: `df[!df$Year %in% c(1992, 2008), ]`

Comment: `df[df$Year > 2008, ]` ?

Comment: Column by number `df[df[,3] != 1992 & df[,2] != 2008,]` or column by name `df[df[,"Year"] != 1992 & df[,"Year"] != 2008,]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`library(dplyr); filter(df, year != 1992 | year != 2008)`

Comment: Or shorter `filter(df, !Year %in% c(1992, 2008))`